# Delete row if next row has the same first value, python

Tags: python, numpy, iteration

I have an array that looks like this:

`data([0.000, 1], [0.0025, 2], [0.0025, 3], [0.005, 5])`

I need to delete [0.0025, 3], because it has the same first value as the one before.

I have tried:

```py
for i in data:
    if data[i, 0] == data[i+1,0]:
        np.delete(data, (i+1), axis = 0)
```

But then I get the following Error:

`IndexError: arrays used as indices must be of integer (or boolean) type`,

Can somebody help me with that

Comment: If its not obvious, there are values that come after [0.005, 5] which need to be deleted too if they repeat themselves like  [0.0025, 2], [0.0025, 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

input:

```
data = np.array([[0.000, 1], [0.0025, 2], [0.0025, 3], [0.005, 5]])
```

solution:

```
data = data[np.unique(data[:,0], return_index=True)[1]]
```

output:

```
array([[0.0e+00, 1.0e+00],
       [2.5e-03, 2.0e+00],
       [5.0e-03, 5.0e+00]])
```

Comment: What does the [1] do?

Comment: @vinc00 `np.unique` returns both unique elements and their indices. Since you need only the indices you take only the `[1]`. Is it clear? Read the `numpy.unique` documentation for more info: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html